# Context nulo al momento de ejecutar AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-studio, android-context

Buen día estoy tratando de ejecutar mi clase SincronizarCodigos, al momento de hacer swipe este ejecuta sincronizar para entrar en un AsyncTask y desde allí ejecutar el metodo que me traería datos del server, según entiendo este entra a Sincronizar y llama a SincronizarCodigos, pero el contexto lo toma como nulo. Existe alguno otra forma de ejecutarlo o cómo podria corregirlo, he tratado de quitarle el contexto , pero al hacerlo no me deja llamar después al método SincronizarCodigos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.formsaide, PID: 5510
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:111)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:268)
        at com.example.formsaide.MainActivityConsultaCodigos$Sincronizar.onPostExecute(MainActivityConsultaCodigos.java:161)
        at com.example.formsaide.MainActivityConsultaCodigos$Sincronizar.onPostExecute(MainActivityConsultaCodigos.java:139)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:679)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5943)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:817)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5510 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:60142', transport: 'socket'
```

Este es mi código:

```
public class MainActivityConsultaCodigos extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ConsultaCodigos();
        //Referenciar AdaptadorCodigos
        AdaptadorCodigos adapter = new AdaptadorCodigos(listaCodigos);
        rvCodigos.setAdapter(adapter);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                new Sincronizar().execute();
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Sincronizar extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        Context context;    
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            SincronizarCodigos(context);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

public void SincronizarCodigos(Context context){
        if(checkConexion(this)){
            
            ConexionSQLiteHelper conex = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(this,"bd_datos",null,1);
            final SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://192.168.0.131/servicio_web/web/obtener_gastos.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response); 
                        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++)
                        {
                            //JSONObject permite obtener un elemento dentro del JSONarray
                            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            conex.GuardarCodigos(
                                    object.getString("idOperario"),
                                    object.getString("Operario"),
                                    object.getString("bloque"),
                                    object.getString("supervisor"),db);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    ConsultaCodigos();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {    
                }
            });
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Por lo que veo, estás declarando el "context", pero no lo inicializas a nada, por eso tiene el valor "NULL", además de que en la función SincronizarCodigos lo pasas como parámetro pero no lo utilizas.
Por otra parte "AsyncTask" te lo marca como obsoleto, igual te convendría usar algún API de conexión a servidor, que la gran mayoría son muy simples de utilizar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema al parecer se produce al tratar de mostrar un Toast pero todo debido al contexto usado que tiene valor null.

Puedes inicializar el contexto dentro del método `onCreate()` de tu `Activity` y este usarlo en el `AsyncTask`

```
Context context;    

public class MainActivityConsultaCodigos extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        //Define contexto en variable context.
        context = getApplicationContext();
        ...
        ...
    }
```

El valor del contexto posteriormente lo usas dentro de tu método `doInBackground()` del `AsyncTask`:

```
   public class Sincronizar extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        //Context context;    
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            SincronizarCodigos(context);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```